# how can I pass data using prepareForSegue in TableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I get an error trying to set indexPath:  **initializer for conditional binding must have optional type**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
    sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toStation" {
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
                as! toStation
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! {
                detailViewController.selectedStation = stationNameArray[indexPath.row]
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

You are binding indexPathForSelectedRow to indexPath view an if let statement to unwrap the optional indexPathForSelectedRow. This is a good approach. But at the same time you are using the bang statement ! to unwrap the optional. Effectively you are unwrapping the optional twice. Either use ! or an if let statement.

Answer (score 0):

You receive this error because `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!` is no longer an optional value (you've unwrapped it). To fix this error, try removing the force unwrap operator `!` at the end of `if let`.

`if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

According to your question subject, I think you are trying to pass Indexpath into `prepareForSegue`, in your case, you can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to pass a `sender`:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toStation", sender: indexPath);
}
```

then in `prepareForSegue` :

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
            if (segue.identifier == "toStation") {
                let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
                    as! toStation 
                let row = (sender as! NSIndexPath).row; //we know that sender is an NSIndexPath here.
                detailViewController.selectedStation = stationNameArray[row]
            }
        }
```

Hope this solve your problem.